# Elasticsearch keep migrating shards out of one of my data node

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Elasticsearch keep migrating shards out of one of my data node *data-mbesdrtp21*. This cluster have mix of plain index and data streams. Half of the data nodes in an availability zone named rtp1 and other half is in an availability zone named rtp2. [Shard Allocation Awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/modules-cluster.html#shard-allocation-awareness) is enabled. Data is sent to elasticsearch via logstash.
Around 10-15 shards get allocated to this node and then they are reallocated to other nodes. Any idea what might be happening here?

- Elasticsearch Version: 7.17.1
- VM Size: 14 CPU, 64GB RAM

**Cluster Settings:**

```
/_cluster/settings?flat_settings=true

{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes": "zone",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force.zone.values": "rtp1,rtp2",
    "xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled": "true"
  },
  "transient": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance": "10",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "all",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_incoming_recoveries": "4",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_outgoing_recoveries": "4",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries": "4",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.node_initial_primaries_recoveries": "4",
    "cluster.routing.rebalance.enable": "all",
    "indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec": "256mb"
  }
}
```

**_cat/allocation**

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent node
   342        5.4tb     5.4tb      2.2tb      7.6tb           71 data-mbesdrtp11
   342        5.7tb     5.7tb      1.7tb      7.4tb           76 data-mbesdrtp110
   342        5.6tb     5.6tb      1.8tb      7.4tb           74 data-mbesdrtp111
   342        5.8tb     5.8tb      1.6tb      7.4tb           78 data-mbesdrtp112
   342        5.6tb     5.6tb      1.8tb      7.4tb           75 data-mbesdrtp12
   342        5.6tb     5.6tb      1.8tb      7.4tb           75 data-mbesdrtp13
   342        5.8tb     5.8tb      1.6tb      7.4tb           78 data-mbesdrtp14
   342        5.6tb     5.6tb      1.8tb      7.4tb           75 data-mbesdrtp15
   341        5.6tb     5.6tb      1.8tb      7.4tb           75 data-mbesdrtp16
   341        5.7tb     5.7tb      1.7tb      7.4tb           76 data-mbesdrtp17
   342        5.7tb     5.7tb      1.7tb      7.4tb           76 data-mbesdrtp18
   341        5.7tb     5.7tb      1.7tb      7.4tb           76 data-mbesdrtp19
     7      150.3gb   156.9gb      7.3tb      7.4tb            2 data-mbesdrtp21
   368        6.3tb     6.3tb      1.1tb      7.4tb           85 data-mbesdrtp210
   374          6tb       6tb      1.3tb      7.4tb           81 data-mbesdrtp211
   367        6.3tb     6.3tb      1.1tb      7.4tb           85 data-mbesdrtp212
   373          6tb       6tb      1.4tb      7.4tb           80 data-mbesdrtp22
   373        6.1tb     6.1tb      1.3tb      7.4tb           81 data-mbesdrtp23
   373        6.2tb     6.2tb      1.2tb      7.4tb           82 data-mbesdrtp24
   373          6tb       6tb      1.4tb      7.4tb           80 data-mbesdrtp25
   373        6.2tb     6.2tb      1.2tb      7.4tb           83 data-mbesdrtp26
   373        6.2tb     6.2tb      1.2tb      7.4tb           83 data-mbesdrtp27
   374        6.1tb     6.1tb      1.3tb      7.4tb           82 data-mbesdrtp28
   373        6.1tb     6.1tb      1.3tb      7.4tb           81 data-mbesdrtp29
```

**elasticsearch.yml** which is same for all the data nodes except for `node.name` and `network.host`:

```
cluster.name: metricbeat-prod
node.name: data-mbesdrtp21
node.roles: [  data_hot , data_content  ]
path.data: ["/apps/elk/data"]
discovery.seed_hosts: [  "mbesmoma2vo", "mbesmrtp11", "mbesmrtp21" ]
path.logs: /apps/elk/logs
network.host: mbesdrtp21.fmr.com
http.port: 9200
bootstrap.memory_lock: True
script.painless.regex.enabled: True
xpack.graph.enabled: false
xpack.ml.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.watcher.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: true
thread_pool.write.queue_size : 5000
node.attr.zone: rtp2
node.attr.box_type: hot
thread_pool.search.queue_size : 10000
xpack.security.enabled: False
http.type: ssl_netty4
s3.client.ceph.endpoint : https://xxx.yyy.com
```

**_cluster/health**

```
{
  "cluster_name": "metricbeat-prod",
  "status": "green",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 29,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 24,
  "active_primary_shards": 4097,
  "active_shards": 8202,
  "relocating_shards": 6,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 100.0
}
```

**ILM details**

```
PUT _ilm/policy/metrics
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_primary_shard_size": "25gb",
            "max_age": "15d"
          }
        }
      },
      "warm": {
        "min_age": "15d",
        "actions": {
          "forcemerge": {
            "max_num_segments": 1
          },
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 50
          },
          "migrate": {
            "enabled": false
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "45d",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {
            "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "_meta": {
      "description": "default policy for the metrics index template installed by x-pack",
      "managed": true
    }
  }
}
```

**_cat/nodeattrs**

```
node                        host                attr            value
data-mbesdrtp24             mbesdrtp24.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp24             mbesdrtp24.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp24             mbesdrtp24.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp24             mbesdrtp24.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp26             mbesdrtp26.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp26             mbesdrtp26.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp26             mbesdrtp26.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp26             mbesdrtp26.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp12             mbesdrtp12.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp12             mbesdrtp12.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp12             mbesdrtp12.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp12             mbesdrtp12.fmr.com  transform.node  false
master-voteonly-mbesmoma2vo mbesmoma2vo.fmr.com xpack.installed true
master-voteonly-mbesmoma2vo mbesmoma2vo.fmr.com transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp22             mbesdrtp22.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp22             mbesdrtp22.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp22             mbesdrtp22.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp22             mbesdrtp22.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp210            mbesdrtp210.fmr.com xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp210            mbesdrtp210.fmr.com box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp210            mbesdrtp210.fmr.com zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp210            mbesdrtp210.fmr.com transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp211            mbesdrtp211.fmr.com xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp211            mbesdrtp211.fmr.com box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp211            mbesdrtp211.fmr.com zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp211            mbesdrtp211.fmr.com transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp212            mbesdrtp212.fmr.com box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp212            mbesdrtp212.fmr.com xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp212            mbesdrtp212.fmr.com zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp212            mbesdrtp212.fmr.com transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp27             mbesdrtp27.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp27             mbesdrtp27.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp27             mbesdrtp27.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp27             mbesdrtp27.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp25             mbesdrtp25.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp25             mbesdrtp25.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp25             mbesdrtp25.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp25             mbesdrtp25.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp111            mbesdrtp111.fmr.com xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp111            mbesdrtp111.fmr.com box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp111            mbesdrtp111.fmr.com zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp111            mbesdrtp111.fmr.com transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp29             mbesdrtp29.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp29             mbesdrtp29.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp29             mbesdrtp29.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp29             mbesdrtp29.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp11             mbesdrtp11.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp11             mbesdrtp11.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp11             mbesdrtp11.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp11             mbesdrtp11.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp110            mbesdrtp110.fmr.com xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp110            mbesdrtp110.fmr.com box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp110            mbesdrtp110.fmr.com zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp110            mbesdrtp110.fmr.com transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp16             mbesdrtp16.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp16             mbesdrtp16.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp16             mbesdrtp16.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp16             mbesdrtp16.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp28             mbesdrtp28.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp28             mbesdrtp28.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp28             mbesdrtp28.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp28             mbesdrtp28.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp21             mbesdrtp21.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp21             mbesdrtp21.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp21             mbesdrtp21.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp21             mbesdrtp21.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp19             mbesdrtp19.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp19             mbesdrtp19.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp19             mbesdrtp19.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp19             mbesdrtp19.fmr.com  transform.node  false
master-mbesmrtp21           mbesmrtp21.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
master-mbesmrtp21           mbesmrtp21.fmr.com  transform.node  false
client-kibana-mbescrtp21    mbescrtp21.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
client-kibana-mbescrtp21    mbescrtp21.fmr.com  transform.node  false
master-mbesmrtp11           mbesmrtp11.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
master-mbesmrtp11           mbesmrtp11.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp14             mbesdrtp14.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp14             mbesdrtp14.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp14             mbesdrtp14.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp14             mbesdrtp14.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp23             mbesdrtp23.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp23             mbesdrtp23.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp23             mbesdrtp23.fmr.com  zone            rtp2
data-mbesdrtp23             mbesdrtp23.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp112            mbesdrtp112.fmr.com box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp112            mbesdrtp112.fmr.com xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp112            mbesdrtp112.fmr.com zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp112            mbesdrtp112.fmr.com transform.node  false
client-kibana-mbescrtp11    mbescrtp11.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
client-kibana-mbescrtp11    mbescrtp11.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp18             mbesdrtp18.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp18             mbesdrtp18.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp18             mbesdrtp18.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp18             mbesdrtp18.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp17             mbesdrtp17.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp17             mbesdrtp17.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp17             mbesdrtp17.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp17             mbesdrtp17.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp15             mbesdrtp15.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp15             mbesdrtp15.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp15             mbesdrtp15.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp15             mbesdrtp15.fmr.com  transform.node  false
data-mbesdrtp13             mbesdrtp13.fmr.com  xpack.installed true
data-mbesdrtp13             mbesdrtp13.fmr.com  box_type        hot
data-mbesdrtp13             mbesdrtp13.fmr.com  zone            rtp1
data-mbesdrtp13             mbesdrtp13.fmr.com  transform.node  false
```

**cluster.routing**: _cluster/settings?filter_path=*.cluster.routing.*

```
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster": {
      "routing": {
        "allocation": {
          "awareness": {
            "attributes": "zone",
            "force": {
              "zone": {
                "values": "rtp1,rtp2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transient": {
    "cluster": {
      "routing": {
        "rebalance": {
          "enable": "all"
        },
        "allocation": {
          "node_concurrent_incoming_recoveries": "4",
          "cluster_concurrent_rebalance": "10",
          "node_concurrent_recoveries": "4",
          "node_initial_primaries_recoveries": "4",
          "enable": "all",
          "node_concurrent_outgoing_recoveries": "4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the response you get from `GET _cat/nodeattrs?v` please?

Comment: @Val added cat/nodeattrs

Comment: Thanks, also can you share `GET _cluster/settings?filter_path=cluster.routing.*` ?

Comment: @Val added that as well

Comment: Anything useful from `GET _cluster/allocation/explain` ?

Comment: @Val I was getting for "node_name": "data-mbesdrtp21". {
                   "decider": "throttling",
                   "decision": "THROTTLE",
                    "explanation": "reached the limit of incoming shard recoveries [2], cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_incoming_recoveries=2] (can also be set via [cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries])"
                }So I removed all the transient settings and now I can see shards are being assigned to this node. Is is slow as 2 shards are relocating at a time. Hopefully by tomorrow all will be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared all the transient settings and now shards are getting back to this node. Looks like this happened because of this open [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/87279) which is causing redundant shard movements.